# Phonegap Build: Access origin doesn't appear to work for subdomains

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

In Phonegap I need to display some images from a CDN which uses multiple subdomains. For example:

```
<img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/.....75.jpg">
<img src="http://a2.mzstatic.com/.....75.jpg">
<img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/.....75.jpg">
<img src="http://a4.mzstatic.com/.....75.jpg">
```

Because these are external resources on multiple subdomains I set the following in my config.xml :

`<access origin="http://mzstatic.com*" subdomains="true" />`

However all the images display broken as if it can't make the call to the server. I added:

`<access origin="http://a1.mzstatic.com*" />`

and images on that domain start to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

To demonstrate this and eliminate all other factors I've forked the phonegap-start project to here https://github.com/SeanBannister/phonegap-start which demonstrates my problem, I've just added my images elements and the access origin to the config.

**Update** The CDN has an unlimited number of subdomains so I can't just list them all.

Answer (score 2):

give a try to `<access origin="http://*.mzstatic.com" />`

Comment: What PG version are you using? Check this link [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)

Comment: what platform? android, iphone?  Do you check http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html ?

Comment: and just for test: if you set it as `<access origin="*" />` also for the test, please remove other <access origin> lines

Comment: Yeah * definitely works but goes against best practices, but does make me think there's a bug in PhoneGap Build.

Comment: And I'm testing on Android.

Comment: It worked for me with cordova 3.5.0 (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mixing what worked for the 1 domain for you:

`<access origin="http://a1.mzstatic.com*" />`

and the answer @Aguardientico said and did something along the line of....

`<access origin="http://*.mzstatic.com*" />`

And sorry would have just posted as a comment on @Aguardientico but not enough rep :(

**Update 1**

After looking at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml, have you tried:

`<access origin="http://*.mzstatic.com*" subdomains="true" />` (Or maybe some variance of the "origin" talked about before)

**Update 2**

Alright after an hour or two of trying various combination... The option that I was only able to get to work was `<access origin="*" />` Naturally though this isn't good practice to allow everything but it seems like it's the only thing that works right now... The PG/Cordova folks really ought to update their documentation on to why it isn't working.

Comment: Hi Drew, I actually did try exactly what you suggested when Aguardientico posted.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind. I'm blind and can't read that you already tried that.

Comment: Updated answer again... I tried as many combinations I could think of but the only one that would work was `<access origin="*"/>`

Comment: Yeah * definitely works but goes against best practices, but does make me think there's a bug in PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score -1):

you need to try this:

```
<access origin="http://*.mzstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```

first * will allow any character before the host/domain name 
& second * will allow any character after "/"

This should work.